# No Such Element Exception:

Tags: java, exception

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AsphaltingRoads {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, t;
        int[] num = new int[3];
        for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = in.nextInt();
            num[i] = n;
        }
        for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            if (num[i] > num[i + 1]) {
                t = num[i];
                num[i] = num[i + 1];
                num[i + 1] = t;
            }
        }
        int dis = (num[2] - num[1]) + (num[3] - num[2]);
        System.out.print(dis);
    }
}
```

I am getting `NoSuchElementException` for above code. What is the reason?

Comment: Properly format your code, we cant see anything

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Remove the equals in i <= 3 in your for loops. You're trying to access index 3 which doesn't exist (remember arrays start from 0 to n). In this case we have [0,1, 2]

Comment: @Shruti `NoSuchElementException` can be only thrown by `in.nextInt()`, in the future please attach a stacktrace and say where the exception is thrown. What is the input you are passing into this program? From the documentation, this exception is thrown "if input is exhausted".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
int []num=new int[3];
```

So you have 3 elements in your array (indexes 0,1,2).

You can't get num[3] element

You should also rewrite for loops.

Comment: This problem will cause `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, not `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: thanx that solves it